# Link to go to and open toggle div

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle, toggleclass

I want a working .jquery toggle to be activated from a nav menu link. I also want the page to scroll to the opened div at the same time. This is working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$(".toggle_container3").hide(); 
$(".trigger3").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
})

});
```

with this HTML:

```
<h4 class="trigger3 dark_grey">
<a href="#">Research Themes</a></h4>
<div class="toggle_container3" id="research"> content </div>
```

And this menu link goes to the research themes section on the page:

```
<li><a href="#research">Research Themes</a></li>
```

But I want the Research Themes link to go to and toggle open the research div. I tried adding the class .trigger3 to the , no luck. The #research stopped working. After researching on this forum, I tried:

```
$('#research').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).toggleClass("").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
window.location.hash = ($(e.currentTarget).attr("href"));
});
```

But no luck. Is there something I can add to the original .trigger3 click function, that will make it work with the  as well? Plus go to that spot on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is the code below, above each div you wish to show/hide add a button with class .trigger and it will toggle the div below it. This would create an accordion. If the buttons cannot be right above each div to toggle you can add a data-toggle='div name' to each button and use that tag to select the div to toggle.

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow"); // toggle div below button
    $('.' + $(this).data('toggle')).slideToggle('slow'); // toggle div specified in data-toggle attribute on trigger element
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
})
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. The div is working already with a "button" - the h4 is toggling the correct div. I want an additional link in a nav menu to also toggle the div (I can add unqiue id's to each div, to match up with each menu link). And I want it to go to the spot of the div on the page. Although - are you saying that I can add the data-toggle to each link and that will work?

Comment: So you want two different buttons to toggle the same div? If so then add the .trigger class to both buttons and reference the div directly by id or class. Such as $('#divid').slideToggle('slow');

Comment: What about the go to on the page part?

Comment: If it is on click then you can add href='#idofelement' to scroll to that element. If you wish to do this in jQuery you can do document.scrollTop = $('#idofelement').position.top();

Comment: Actually, I think I just had to remove the return false; from the script, that now does allow the browser to jump to the link anchor. Thanks for the help - I think its all working the way I want now.